# How to filter on the value of a specific element in a list?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

Using GAE-Java-JDO, is it possible to filter on the value of a specific element in a list?

## WHAT WORKS

Normally, I would have the following:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class A {

  String field1;
  String field2;

  // id, getters and setters

}
```

Then I would build a simple query:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(A.class, "field1 == val");
q.declareParameters("String val");
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>((List<A>) q.execute("foo"));
```

## WHAT I WOULD LIKE

The above works fine. But what I would like to have is all of the fields stored in a list:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class AA {

  ArrayList<String> fields;

  // id, getters and setters

}
```

and then be able to query on a specific field in the list:

```
int index = 0;
Query q = pm.newQuery(A.class, "fields.get(index) == val");
q.declareParameters("int index, String val");
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>((List<A>) q.execute(index, "foo"));
```

But this throws an exception:

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$UnsupportedDatastoreFeatureException:
Problem with query 
<SELECT FROM xxx.AA WHERE fields.get(index) == val PARAMETERS int index, String val,>:     
Unsupported method <get> while parsing expression: 
InvokeExpression{[PrimaryExpression{strings}].get(ParameterExpression{ui})}
```

My impression from reading [the GAE-JDO doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) is that this is not possible:

> "The property value must be supplied by the application; it cannot refer to or be calculated in terms of other properties"

So... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to filter by index+value, then I think prefixing the actual list-values with their index should work. (If you need to also filter by actual values, then you'll need to store both lists.)

i.e. instead of the equivalent of

`fields= ['foo', 'bar', 'baz]` with query-filter `fields[1] == 'bar'`

you'd have

`fields= ['0-foo', '1-bar', '2-baz']` with query-filter `fields == '1-bar'`

(but in java)

Comment: No luck. I tried declaring two parameters (the index and the value), but this query: `SELECT FROM xxx.AA WHERE fields == 'index-val' PARAMETERS String index, String val,` doesn't return any results (when it should be returning one).

Comment: hmm... I don't understand that code :( If it wasn't clear though, you have to change what you store to be a new value that is made from combining (by you) the index and the value, there's nothing automatic/inherent that solves the problem.